# Why my GeckoFX browser doesn't load videos?

Tags: c#, xulrunner, geckofx

I'm using C# + GeckoFX-18.0 (bitbucket.org/geckofx) for developing a web browser, but when I visit a page which contains a video, it simply doesn't load the video - the area of the video stays all black. I have Firefox 21.0 installed and the videos load without any problem.

Note: Youtube videos are not loading ...

My code is pretty basic for now:

```
private GeckoWebBrowser wb = null;

// main form constructor
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Xpcom.Initialize("C:\\mybrowser\\mybrowser\\xulrunner");

    wb = new GeckoWebBrowser();
    wb.Parent = this;
    wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    wb.Navigated += new EventHandler<GeckoNavigatedEventArgs>(browser_Navigated);

}

void browser_Navigated(object sender, GeckoNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    GeckoWebBrowser wb = (GeckoWebBrowser)sender;
}
```

Comment: Is that plugin-based video or HTML5 video tag?

Comment: I guess the problem is only with plugin-based videos because Youtube videos are not loading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you try with the following line of code right after `Xpcom.Initialize("..");` :

```
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.Default["extensions.blocklist.enabled"] = false;
```

This has worked for me with GeckoFX18